# More efficient way to find content of files within millions of files

Tags: command-line, grep, find

We currently have a series of files ordered by date, by type and then individual XML files containing details, with the basic structure as:

```
2020-01-01/
    FR_abc
        FR_abc_datetime_random.xml
        FR_abc_datetime_random.xml
        ...
        FR_abc_datetime_random.xml
    FR_def
        FR_def_datetime_random.xml
        FR_def_datetime_random.xml
        ...
        FR_def_datetime_random.xml
    FR_ghi
        FR_ghi_datetime_random.xml
        FR_ghi_datetime_random.xml
        ...
        FR_ghi_datetime_random.xml
    ...
    FR_xyz
        FR_xyz_datetime_random.xml
        FR_xyz_datetime_random.xml
        ...
        FR_xyz_datetime_random.xml
```

This filesystem is pruned frequently, but we often have between 120 and 150 million files in the structure. Sometimes we'll need to interrogate one of the files and sometimes we'll know the date we need to look at, and sometimes not. If we know which dates we are looking at, we use a simple command to inspect for the text we are looking for with:

```
ls -U | xargs grep -l TEXT
```

Which lists the files with the specific TEXT which we can then interrogate manually.

If we know the type of file and the text to look for, I'm currently using the find command, thus:

```
find . -type f -name "^FR_ghi*" | xargs grep -l TEXT
```

Others in the group use the ls command with a recursive (-R) flag.

With these commands, the search takes a long time, over a day - I was wondering if anyone knew a way to speed this up, or any replacement commands to provide a faster turn around time?

-- edit1 --

The TEXT parameter can be anywhere in the file, and these files are on a Production box, so I'd be hesitant to add another process on that box as these queries are ad-hoc and I guess my initial query is more "are we doing this the right way / does someone have a better way"?

Comment: You will need an indexing search system to have faster searches for text within many files. You may want to explore recoll.

Comment: have you tried `grep -l TEXT FR_ghi/FR_ghi*`?

Comment: I have no experience using recoll on large data sets, but on my notebook it has proven invaluable for finding things. It has very powerful search functions that I have only slightly used. It does however build large index files - which would be quite a bit larger and take longer to create/update in this situation. Make sure you have a lot of free disk space when you test it.

Comment: Can the TEXT be anywhere in the file? When it is always on the first line or a line starting with some tag like `<you want me>TEXT</you want me>`, you might want to extract those lines first and search through these meta-files (perhaps per-day).

Comment: Can you insert the XML-files in some database?

Comment: added edit1 for some clarifications ...

Answer (score 0):

You can test something like

```
time head -12 <(yes "1") | xargs -n1 -P4 sleep
```

This will run 12 `sleep 1` commands, 4 parallel. The command will take 3 seconds.
In your case:

```
find . -type f -name "^FR_ghi*" | xargs -n1 -P4 grep -l TEXT
```

I do not know how many CPU threads you have, perhaps -P8 is also possible.
When the commands are I/O bounded, this might be of little help. In that case it might be interesting to store all `xml` files in gzipped format and use `zgrep`.